# I keep getting a Level Factor when trying to change a cell in a Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, r-factor

I dont know whats happening, Im just trying to import a table and change a few values, but I keep getting the same thing and I don't know whats happening.

I have something like this: The table in Excel, which I convert to a .csv.
This is what the csv looks like:

```
Names Year1 Year2 Year3
Name1  200   200   500
Name2  100   500   350
Name3  300   600    50
```

Then I try to import with this code:

```
data <- read.csv("table.csv",sep=";",header=T)
data[2,2]
[1] 100
Levels: 300 100 200
data[2,2] <- 500
Mensagens de aviso perdidas:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 500) :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
```

It's in portuguese, the translation is something like 
**Mensagens de aviso perdidas** = Warning messages lost

Comment: Try `data <- read.csv("table.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: Why would R interpret integers as factors?

Comment: @SeñorO, perhaps some character values later in the same column. Try, for example: `x <- tempfile(); cat("Name;Year1", "Name1;100", "Name2;x", sep = "\n", file=x); str(read.csv(x, sep = ";", quote="'"))`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto That was my thought, but it doesn't look like there are other character values later because the output says `Levels: 300 100 200`.

Comment: Same here. I doubt OP ran `droplevels` after subsetting for reproducibility...

Comment: first when you import a file with read.csv the resulting object is not a matrix but a data frame. When you have a factor, the only possible values are the level values. Therefore when you try to assign 500 to data[2,2] it says that "500" is not an allowed values as your levels for this column are "300", "100" & "200". "500" is not comprised in the accepted list of value. You have to first check why numerical values could be transformed into factors, and then do :    data[,2] <- as.numeric(as.character(data[,2]))    . If you don't do that the factors would not be correctly transformed.